# Extjs checkbox setValue based on 1 and 0

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I have a checkbox on my form panel,

And I'm on the process where I need to edit a data based on id in MySQL database where there is a option for checkbox 1=checked 0=not checked,

how do I get the value of, for example, the field of checkbox and put it on a conditional clause and set the value checked to checkbox if it is 1 and not checked if it returns 0?...

Answer (score 16):

Need to set to the checkbox config

```
inputValue: '1',
uncheckedValue: '0'
```

You can check the documentation at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-cfg-uncheckedValue

Answer (score 1):

All checks do not consider the event check if the value is a string. I created a fix. Add before Ext.onReady

```
Ext.override
(
    Ext.form.Checkbox,
    {
        setValue:function(v){

            var checked = this.checked, inputVal = this.inputValue;

            if(v === false)
            {
                this.checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.checked = (v === true || v === 'true' || v == '1' || (v instanceof String) || (inputVal ? v == inputVal : String(v).toLowerCase() == 'on'));
            }

            if(this.rendered)
            {
                this.el.dom.checked = this.checked;
                this.el.dom.defaultChecked = this.checked;
            }
            if(checked != this.checked)
            {
                this.fireEvent('check', this, this.checked);
                if(this.handler)
                {
                    this.handler.call(this.scope || this, this, this.checked);
                }
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
);


{
    xtype:'checkbox', 
    fieldLabel:'Caption', 
    labelSeparator:':', 
    boxLabel:'LabelText', 
    name:'status', 
    inputValue:'0'
}
```

inputValue must be a String '0'.

Answer (score 0):

this issue has been resolved,

by using 1 checkbox per field, there is no problem at all!....

the checkbox will get checked when the fieldname assigned to it returns a value of 1,

that's it!,

....